# append filename to each line

Tags: bash, unix, append, line

I need to add the filename at the end of each line..
this is how I do it..

```
 files=($(ls | grep -i -E 'XYZ_')) 

 length=${#files[*]}
 for ((i=0;i<=$(($length - 1)); i++)) 
 do
    sed "s/$/$(basename ${files[$i]}) /g" ${files[$i]} >> output
 done
```

The problem is the result..

here's a line
20170302105D AAA.AAAE AR       1111 HHH1,0PPP

here's how it **could** be

> 20170302105D AAA.AAAE AR       1111 HHH1,0PPPXYZ_FILENAME

**or**

> 20170302105D AAA.AAAE AR       1111 HHH1,0PPP XYZ_FILENAME

Here's instead the result

> 20170302105D AAA.AAAE AR       1111 HHH1,0PPP
>
> XYZ_FILENAME
>
> 20160307205D bbb.bbbE AR       12511 HHH1,0PPP
>
> XYZ_FILENAME

So it appends the filename as a new line..
How can I solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out that Windows line endings were causing the issues.

---

Anyhow I recommend to use this single `awk` command for that.

```
awk '{print $0, FILENAME}' *XYZ_*
```

(that's all, no shell loop)

Comment: Nope..I get the same result

Comment: Looks like the input file has windows line endings? If yes, convert them to UNIX before running `awk` on it

Comment: The same, but with printf - awk '{printf $0, FILENAME}' *XYZ_*

Comment: Not sure why you want to use printf, but the right command would be `awk '{printf "%s %s\n", $0, FILENAME}' file`